# python regex ignoring text

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of imperfections in my code:
the list contains the name of a procedure its parameters and the one parameter that I have to change adding 'CONST' in front of it

I'd like to find all the procedures that matches the pattern
name of the procedure (list of parameters plus comments all over the place)

i.e.
imperfection in the code    PROCEDURE TEST (X : STRING; Y: STRING); (Y NEEDS CONST)

I'd like to find the procedure
    PROCEDURE TEST (X : STRING; {SOME COMMENTS HERE}  Y: STRING {SOME MORE COMMENTS HERE});

and then add the word CONST before Y: STRING to finally get

```
PROCEDURE TEST (X : STRING; {SOME COMMENTS HERE}  CONST Y: STRING {SOME COMMENTS HERE});
```

consider that we can have {SOME COMMENTS HERE} repeated ntimes in nplaces and in the final version I want to keep the comments

I know there are other possibilities but I'd like to do that with regular expressions
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried writing a regex to do what you want?

Comment: Is "SOME COMMENTS HERE" allowed to contain `{` and `}`?  If so, then do you expect them to get "paired up"?  If so, then this isn't possible with regexps.  If not (e.g., if `}` isn't allowed to appear in the comments), then should be possible.

Comment: Sorry, I want very clear in the explanation of my problem, I added some more info in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
import re

with open('lines', 'r') as input:
for line in input:
    match = re.search('PROCEDURE TEST \(X : STRING;\s*(\{.*\})*\s*Y: STRING\);', line)
    if match:
        print 'PROCEDURE TEST (X : STRING;', match.group(1), 'CONST Y: STRING);'
```

***[Edit:]*** Ok, so from what I can understand of your description you have two files: a list of all imperfections containing each suggested correction in the same line (this is 'imperfections' in my code) and another file where you actually want to apply the suggested fixes ('code').

If the procedure name is actually a parameter you want to match, and the examples you gave us are correct (you always have a ';' after variable declarations and before comments **except for** the last variable, where you don't have a ';') this code should do.

Uncomment the 'print' line if you want to see the regexp that is being searched.

```
import re

with open('imperfections', 'r') as imp:
  imperfections = imp.readlines()
with open('code', 'r') as cod:
  code = cod.readlines()
for imp in imperfections:
  parsed = re.search('(.*); \((\w+) NEEDS (\w+)', imp)
  find = parsed.group(1).replace('(', '\(')
  find = find.replace(')', '\s*(\{.*\})*\)')
  find = find.replace(';', ';\s*(\{.*\})*')
  replace = parsed.group(2)
  replace_with = ' '.join([parsed.group(3), replace])
  #print 'find: "%s" replace "%s" with "%s"' % (find, replace, replace_with)
  for line in code:
    match = re.search(find, line)
    if match:
        print re.sub(replace, replace_with, line)[:-1]
```

[***2nd edit*** - I forgot you want to keep the comments:] To ignore anything that's between braces you may just create a temporary string removing text between braces and match against that. Then, you use `difflib` to merge the two strings.
This is with one of your examples, change it to do the iteration over all lines.

```
import re
import difflib

def merge(string1, string2):
  diffs = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, string2, string1).get_opcodes()
  result = ''
  last_index = 0
  for diff in [x for x in diffs if x[0] in ['insert', 'replace']]:
    if diff[0] == 'replace':
      result += string2[last_index:diff[1]] + string1[diff[3]:diff[4]] + string2[diff[1]:diff[2]]
    else:
      result += string2[last_index:diff[1]] + string1[diff[3]:diff[4]]
    last_index = diff[2]
  result += string2[last_index:]
  return result

original = "PROCEDURE TEST (X: STRING; {Hi, I'm a comment} Y: INT {me too!})"
stripped = re.sub(r'\s*\{[^}]*\}\s*', '', original)

if re.search('PROCEDURE TEST \(X: STRING;Y: INT\)', stripped):
  correct = stripped.replace('Y', 'CONST Y')
  print merge(original, correct)
```

Comment: almost there, you can put comments between any variable in the procedure declaration, I wanted some way to ignore ALL comments (anything between {})

Comment: I forgot to say that the "procedure test" and whats after const y: string are variable, I'd like to substitution to work on any procedure declaration that's why in the question I was asking how to ignore the text

Comment: so every "procedure" has 2 parameters? do lines follow this pattern? 

`"[uppercase chars and white spaces] ([single uppercase char]: [uppercase chars]; [{optional comment}] [single uppercase char]: [uppercase chars] [{optional comment}]);"`

Comment: to answer the edit, all the lines in my firt file contains line numbers and name of variables that needs to be prefixed by "const", in my source code file at the line number i find the declaration of a procedure with a list of variables, after some more lines (I don't know exactly where) i find the implementation of the procedure, again with the same parameters but with possibly comments between the parameters, that's why I "simply" wanted to find a match of my procedure declaration (with lots of \s* between each parameter) ignoring the comments part

Comment: well, I'd say that my example is close enough to what you want to do.. you should be able to tweak the code to suit whatever your actual problem is; there's no point in trying to come up with a solution that's good for you if you don't state precisely what your problem is in the first place..

Comment: I thought my question was clear: forget about files, forget about parameters, the basic question was: how can I match (using python regex) my "phrase" to a phrase which is the same if you ignore anything between {}

Comment: you just add a bunch of `(\{.*\})*` like I did, or you can simply remove anything that's between `{` and `}` in every line you're iterating on and match against that; then you simply make the substitution in the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something as simple as the following?

```
result = re.sub("Y:", "CONST Y:", subject)
```

If its too simple let us know. Maybe you want all second argument to receive a CONST regardless of the name (in this case Y) ?

Comment: I guess I could have explained more, my file contains several procedures delcarations, a lot of them have y: string i only have to modify one of those procedures based on the parameter list

Comment: ok, and what is the criteria to zoom in on just one of those procedures? That sounds key to constructing the regex

Comment: the list of parameters and the name of the procedure defines the one procedure: you take the procedure with comments, take away the comments (anything between {}) and it matches the procedure i want to find

Comment: its practice at stackoverflow to edit the original question FYI